# Showing all divs/elements under parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that hides all divs (and all of the elements within). Immediately after, a "show" javascript function is called but I only want to show one section of the page and the children divs under it.

For example, I have:

```
<div id="synchronize" style="display:none;">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <h4>HEADER</h4>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>more text.</p>
    </li>
    <li>hello
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When bxslider is used, there are several more divs added to the mix once the javascript for that is called.

Here is my javascript:

```
var theID="synchronize"; //(this value is actually passed in)
div = document.getElementById(theID);
div.style.display = 'block';

$('div#synchronize').children('div').each(function () {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

The alert is giving "undefined". Seems like this should be easy, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no child divs under parent #synchronize

Comment: And a DIV doesn't have a value ?

Comment: It says divs were added dynamically

Answer (score 0):

`.value` would refer to a form field element, not a DOM element. You may want `this.innerHTML/this.innerText` or its kin, or with jquery `$(this).text()`

Comment: Another note `#synchronize` has no children `divs`. Your solution still alert `undefined` unless the children should be there.

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements don't have values.  use `alert($(this).attr('innerText'));`

EDIT: op asked for how to get all nested elements.

This will return all sub elements of an element.

Using this html:

```
<div id="synchronize" style="display:none;">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <h4>HEADER</h4>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>more text.</p>
    </li>
    <li>hello
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

javascript-- the * selector gets all child elements, regardless of nesting level.

```
$('#synchronize *').each(function(){
   // do stuff here.
   // create a jquery object from the current element:
   var $element = $(this);

   // set a css value, for example:
   $element.css('display', 'block'); //uses jquery.
   this.style.display = 'block'; //uses pure javascript.
});
```

Comment: or `this.innerText` if you prefer a pure javascript approach at that point.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about changing the css of a child? this.css.style.display = 'block';?????

Comment: I also have $('div#synchronize').children('div').each(function ()...I don't want just the "div" children, but all children (I chose div for testing the functionality). How do I get ALL children?

Comment: @JenMason, I addressed your other questions.  New questions that are off topic from the original should have a new question thread created.